# adjust section according to country?

Tags: php, plugin-development, ajax, jquery

Mauritius +
Mexico +
Micronesia, Federated States of -
Monaco +
Mongolia +
Montenegro +
Morocco +
Mozambique -
Myanmar -
Namibia -
Nauru -
Nepal +
Netherlands +
New Zealand +
Nicaragua -
Niger -
Nigeria -
Norway +
Oman +
Pakistan +
Palau -
Panama +
Papua New Guinea -
Paraguay +
Peru +
Philippines-
Poland +
Portugal +
Puerto Rico -
Qatar +
Republic of Korea + 
Republic of Moldova 0
Romania +
Russian Federation 0

NOTE:
 There are 3 type of Countries.(some countries in list have signed “-”,“+” and “0”)
(“-”) signed countries in list people can not obtain E-Visa. When applications apllied from these countries
Please Note 
! Due to the absence of the selected country of nationality in the list of e-Visa eligible countries, issuing a visa has failed. For more information, it is recommended to contact us by e-mail.

(“+”) signed countries in list people can obtain E-Visa. When applications apllied from these countries
Dont note any thing automaticly passed next step for application

(“0”) signed countries  in list people can cross the border without visa ( visa free ). When applications apllied from these countries
Please Note 
! Entry into Azerbaijan is exempt from a visa due to the selected country of nationality and the type of the travel document. You can stay in the territory of Azerbaijan for up to 30 days. For more information, it is recommended to contact us by e-mail.

I have to show all content according to this sheet .. how can i do this

thanx in advance